# active link with css sliding down

Tags: html, css

I have one problem with my `CSS` code.

The problem is active link sliding down.

This is my [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/AtLyr) page link from codepen .

If you check my *DEMO* page then you see blue border color active links. I want that links come on the al the images. But now 5,6,7 numbers picture active link blue border sliding down. What can i do here anyone can help me?

```
.slider-control-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 96px;
    height: 71px;
    float:left;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-left:16px;
    margin-top:5px;


}
.slider-control-nav a.active { 
  border:2px solid #3978f5; 
  opacity:1; 
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px 3px #777777;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px 3px #777777;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px 3px #777777;
  width: 97px;
  height: 72px;

}
.imgtmb img {
    width:97px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radis:3px;
    -o-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    }
.imgtmb {
    float: left;
width: 97px;
height: 72px;
margin-left: 16px;
margin-top: 6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `slider-control-nav` section from within `img_tb` and place it above.

Increase `.container`'s width to not force the images below